# SQL Select query gave a duplicate results

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working with the two Oracle example tables, Emp and Dept.

I made this query:

```
SELECT ENAME,DNAME,LOC FROM EMP INNER JOIN DEPT ON EMP.DEPTNO = 10.
```

The number 10 is the dept id in the Dept table. I just want to retrieve the records with the deptid 10. The query works but it gave me duplicated records.

Here are the results:

```
ENAME        DNAME        LOC        DEPTNO
=========    ==========   ========   ======
JAMES        ACCOUNTING   NEW YORK   10
CLARK KEN    ACCOUNTING   NEW YORK   10
JAMES        RESEARCH     DALLAS     20
CLARK KEN    RESEARCH     DALLAS     20
JAMES        SALES        CHICAGO    30
CLARK KEN    SALES        CHICAGO    30
JAMES        OPERATIONS   BOSTON     40
CLARK KEN    OPERATIONS   BOSTON     40
```

As you can see, the first two records match the query and the same records are duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `on` criteria and then add `where` criteria instead:

```
SELECT ENAME,DNAME,LOC 
FROM EMP 
     INNER JOIN DEPT ON EMP.DEPTNO = DEPT.DEPTNO
WHERE DEPT.DEPTNO = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no where clause.

```
SELECT ENAME,DNAME,LOC FROM EMP WHERE DEPTNO = 10
```